# SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIF match three criteria

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, countif

I have a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQqWW.jpg) of three columns - salespersoncode, debtoraccount and salesinvoicedate:

[image]

I need to calculate how many times the salesperson has serviced the debtor.  It needs to separate by date (weekly range, for example week 1, 2 or 3), different salesperson code, and different debtor account. I already customize a simple [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9boUg.jpg) but I can't get the formula right:
 [image]

Here's my formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Sales!A:A,A2,Sales!C:C,"*"))
```

Comment: Add pictures into the question please.

Comment: What defines the start and stop of Week1, Week2, etc? Is `=TEXT(WEEKNUM(TODAY()), "\W\e\e\k 0")` correct as **Week 46**?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first posting. The month define the week, let say on October: 

week 1 is 01/10 - 03/10, 
week 2 is 05/10 - 10/10, 
week 3 is 12/10 - 16/10, week 4 is 19/10 - 23/10 and week 5 is 26/10 - 31/10.

Comment: Can you use column D as a helper column to define the week number from the date?

Comment: I'm thinking it would lend itself to a pivot table with the rows as salesperson and debtor account and the columns as week number (you would need to include the salesperson name somehow but I don't think that would be a problem)

Comment: I can add another row on top of the table, which state the date let say from 01/10/15 to 03/10/15 for week 1, that way it would  refer to the original data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your question, yes it would be easy to set up a formula like this if you had the date ranges stored somewhere (starting from D2 in this example) and the debtor ID stored somewhere (C2 in this example):-

```
=COUNTIFS(Sales!$A$2:$A$10,$A4,Sales!$B$2:$B$10,$C$2,Sales!$C$2:$C$10,">="&D$2,Sales!$C$2:$C$10,"<="&D$3)
```

but it's more labour intensive than the pivot table method.

[image]

The Sales sheet:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mister. I just solved it and it is the exactly data that i was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: I have another similar question, it the exactly same as above, but with amount, I need it to sum the amount together. Or can you please refer to my other question? Thanks.

Comment: I think the advice is to ask a new question, although the answer should be very similar. Also, the amounts that need to be added aren't shown in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This may not suit you but is about the only sensible way to address the problem in general: the ubiquitous PivotTable. Assuming `SALESPERSONCODE` is in A1, add a column to your source data populated with a label (say `W#`) and something like `=WEEKNUM(C2)` in Row2 and copied down to suit. Then in a PT:

ROWS: `SALESPERSONCODE`
COLUMNS: `W#`
VALUES: Count of `DEBTORACCOUNT`

Add a further column (populated from  look up table, say with VLOOKUP) and include that under `SALESPERSONCODE` in ROWS if you want to display names next to codes (in which case use Show in Tabular Form for Layout - Report Layout).

Once you have the PT, many other views of the same data are readily available.